# How may I store images in a database using the Inubit tool set?

Tags: java, php, xml, xslt

I am learning Inubit. I want to know, how may I store images in a database using the Inubit tool set?

Answer (score 1):

The question is more than a year old. I guess you solved it by now.

For all others coming here, let me sketch out the typical way you'd do that.

**0. (optional) Compress data.**
Depending on the compression of the image (e.g. its GIF, PDF, uncompressed TIFF, etc. and not JPEG), you might want to compress it via a *Compressor module* first to reduce needed database space and increase overall performance on the next steps. Be sure to compress the binary data and not the base64-encoded string (see next step)!

**1. Encode binary stream to base64.**

Depending on where you get the image
    data from, chances are that it already is base64 encoded. E.g. you
    used a *file connector* to retrieve it from disk with the appropriate option checked or used a *web service
    connector*. If you really have a binary data stream, convert it to
    base64 using an *encoder module* (better self-documenting) or using a variable
    assignment using the XPATH-function *isxp:encode* (more concise).

**2. Save the encoded data via a *database connector*.**

Well, the details
    for doing this right are pretty much database specific. The cheap
    trick that should work on any database, is storing the base64-string
    simply as a string in a TEXT / CLOB column. This will waste about
    three times as much space in the database as the original binary
    data, since base64 is poorly packed. Doing it right would mean to
    construct a forced SQL query in an XSLT that decodes the
    base64-string to binary and stores it. [Here](http://psoug.org/reference/utl_encode.html) is some reference
    to how it can be done in Oracle.

Hope, this might be of some help.

Cheers,

Jörn

---

Jörn Willhöft

Willhöft IT-Beratung GmbH, Berlin, Germany

Answer (score 0):

You do not store the image in the database, you only record the path to the image. The Image will be stored on the server.

Here is an example of how to store the path to the image : [How to insert multiple images path to database](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/916676-how-insert-multiple-images-path-database)

Comment: I appreciate your answer but that was not match my expectation.. I want to store full image into database. There are so many ways using different language like php,java but I am using Xpath,Xslt and Xml with Inubit.